# How to confirm form when inputs in directives are valid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS project, I have 2 directives with `md-autocomplete` and a block of text, which is hidden by default. My task is to show this block immediately on an event (text in the `input` will be selected from autocomplete in both directives).

Other words, to check both directives and if all autocompletes are selected then show this block.

How can I implement this feature?

```js
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
            $scope.showResults = false;
            $scope.show = function(){
                $scope.showResults = true;
            }
        })

        app.directive('inputDir', function(){
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                templateUrl: autocomplete.html,
                scope: {
                    field: '@'
                },
               link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

                    scope.showResults = false;
                    
                    scope.selectedItem = function () {
                        var isSelected = angular.element(document.querySelector('li')).text();

                        if(isSelected.$valid && angular.isDefined(isSelected)){
                          scope.showResults = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">

        <input-dir field="field1"></input-dir>

        <div class="results" ng-show="showResults">
            <p>Results</p>
        </div>

        <input-dir field="field2"></input-dir>
</body>
</html>

---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
   

 autocomplete.html

  <md-autocomplete class="city" ng-disabled="isDisabled" md-no-cache="noCache" md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text-change="searchTextChange(searchText)" md-search-text="searchText" md-selected-item-change="selectedItemChange(item)" md-items="item in querySearch(searchText)" md-item-text="item.display" md-min-length="0" placeholder="{{place}}">
    <md-item-template >
      <span md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i" >{{item.display}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
  </md-autocomplete>
```

I'm trying to get text from input and check if it's in input and is valid, but my attempts are not successfully

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: can you make fiddle or plunker ?

Comment: It'll be a long chunk of code. which I tried to simplify to show the general idea. what I want.